# Gathering and display table information in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to mysql and php but I'm trying to build a site that tracks the attendance of players at training. For the player dashboard I want to show them their upcoming trainings in their team. I know the teamid variable is actually set properly so thats not the issue. Here's the code thats not working:

```
//find trainings for the team
        $query = 'select trainingid from teamtrain where teamid = "'.$teamid.'"';
        $trainingid = DB::query($query);

        
        //display training info
        echo '<table><tr><th>Start</th><th><Finish></th><th>Location</th></tr>';
        foreach ($trainingid as $trainingid) {

            $infoquery = 'select * from training where id = "'.$trainingid['trainingid'].'" order by startdt asc';
            $training = DB::queryFirstRow($query);

            $location = $training['campus'].' - '.$training['place'];

            printf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',$training['startdt'],$training['finishdt'],$location);

        }
        echo '</table>';
```

it's trying to display all information about a team in my database that you can see in the image but I'm getting these warnings, any ideas:

> Warning: Undefined array key "campus" in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ia2/player.php on line 88
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "place" in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ia2/player.php on line 88
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "startdt" in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ia2/player.php on line 90
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "finishdt" in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ia2/player.php on line 90

I was hoping to retrieve all the information on a teams trainings and display them for the player.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE training`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looking at your code and error messages :

Your this line :

```
$training = DB::queryFirstRow($query);
```

Need to be changed to :

```
$training = DB::queryFirstRow($infoquery);
```

As per your code;

`query` will return you `trainingid`.

`infoquery` will return you the keys `campus`, `place`, `startdt` and `finishdt`